# Visual Studio Setup project sequence control

Tags: asp.net, windows, installation, web-setup-project

Can I run several installers from one installer in a defined succession?

I have a webproject which requires a windows service, which requires a 3rd party converter product.

So I have a WebProject installer which should run itself first (the webproject), then it should run a 3rd party installer and after that the windows service installer.

And that in this order, because the web project and the 3rd party products create registry keys which the windows service installer needs to read. Reading them is easy, but they have to exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from within an MSI project, you'll need a bootstrapper of some description to 'chain' the installations.